# react toggle listen to other node of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm doing a calendar component where the calendar will be closed if the user click on other places. The logic is dead simple, just hide and show using setState on the input to show the calendar. But how do I hide the calendar when user click on elsewhere of the screen?

If it's jquery I can use this logic.

```
$('calendar_input').click(function(){
    if($(this).not('.calendar')) && !$(this).hasClass(.calendar_input)){
       //close calendar
    }
})
```

but how about react?

Answer (score 1):

You can set and event listener on the input

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
}

handleClickOutside(event) {
    if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target)) {
        console.log('You clicked outside of input!');
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div ref={this.setWrapperRef}>
            <input type="text" ref={(ip) => {this.wrapperRef = ip}}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: the input will trigger a calendar, do I have to add ref to the calendar also?

Comment: I am not sure how your component look like, but I don't think it will be required, can you try that out. In case you have a separate component for Calendar, then you can put a ref on that too, and add an extra condition on handleClick elsewhere, a good approach will be to create a separate component for hits so that all your other click don't malfunction

Comment: I have the same use case for input range, basically there's a fake dropdown and it will trigger some slider to open, https://pastebin.com/raw/tQvHJdY1

what should I do in this case?

Comment: Unfortunaltely that link doesn't open on my network. However the idea to check if the click event target is present in the component. So which ever component you want to click outside , make sure your set your condition for that

Comment: Unfortunately not, no codesharing website opens on my network, jsfiddle opens though

Answer (score 0):

i usually using this logic (sorry for my bad english) : Listen for event click and check target is child of "calendar".

In componentWillMount i add event click

```
window.onclick = (event) => {

if(!this.refs.calendar.contains(event.target)){
    //set state close calendar
}}
```

Comment: and the reason you use '`' is?

Comment: here <div ref='calendar'>this is clendar</div>

Comment: use window in a component, I don't feel safe about this.